# SQL server wont start

Tags: macos, mac, mysql, sql

I have a passed down mac which had previously installed mySQL. I tried running the SQL server from preferences but it wont start. Uninstallation wont work either. I ran the command **sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start**. It resulted in the following error.

> Starting MySQL ./usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199:  6557
>   Trace/BPT trap: 5       env MYSQLD_PARENT_PID=6140 nohup
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql
>   --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=APS-16.local.err --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306 < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1  ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).

I have uninstalled mySql forcefully and reinstalled. The error is still persistent.
Commands used to uninstall.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf  /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963171/mysql-server-startup-error-the-server-quit-without-updating-pid-file?page=1&tab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Run the essence of that command manually:

> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql
>   --datadir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=APS-16.local.err --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306

The way it's running now, the STDOUT and STDERR are being sent to /dev/null so you can see any of the output or errors!